# @RequestBody ignores request from android HttpClient

Tags: android, spring-mvc

I have a MVC Controller which takes User object as input.This is deployed on a Tomcat server.
    I test this method with java class Client, the user is populated on server and I see result as expected.
    But when I run the same client code in Android app, the mvc method testSingleObjectIn simply ignores the request.
    The code is as follows.
MVC Controller:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonDeserialize;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.dn.entity.User;
import com.dn.entity.UserInfo;

@Controller
public class MVCControllerTest {
@RequestMapping(value= "/testSingleObjectIn", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public void testSingleObjectIn(@RequestBody User testObj) {

        System.out.println("User ="+testObj.toString());
    }
}
```

Client executed as Java application from within eclipse:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import com.dn.entity.Region;
import com.dn.entity.User;
import com.dn.enums.RegionType;
import com.dn.enums.Salutation;



public class Client {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Client client = new Client();
        client.testSingleObjectInput();
    }
private void testSingleObjectInput(){
        HttpClient httpClient = null;
        try {
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String url = "http://localhost:8080/DNServer/testSingleObjectIn";
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            User user = new User();
            user.setFirstName("XYZ");
            user.setSurName("Abc");
            user.setSalutation(Salutation.Mr);

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            System.out.println( mapper.writeValueAsString(user));
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(mapper.writeValueAsString(user)));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            System.out.println("testSingleObjectInput done");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

Android AsyncTask:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.dn.entity.User;

public class RegistrationTask extends AsyncTask<User, Integer, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(User... users) {

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/DNServer/testSingleObjectIn";
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println( mapper.writeValueAsString(users[0]));
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(mapper.writeValueAsString(users[0])));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

User VO:

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.dn.enums.Salutation;

public class User implements Serializable {

```
long userId;
String firstName;
String surName;
Salutation salutation; 

public User() {
}

public User(long userId, String firstName, String surName, Salutation salutation) {
    super();
    this.userId = userId;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.surName = surName;
    this.salutation = salutation;
}

public long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}


public String getSurName() {
    return surName;
}

public void setSurName(String surName) {
    this.surName = surName;
}

public Salutation getSalutation() {
    return salutation;
}

public void setSalutation(Salutation salutation) {
    this.salutation = salutation;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
  return salutation.toString()+" firstName ="+ firstName+"  LastName= "+surName;
}
```

}